# .net standard 2 reference with enums break on .net 4.7.1 but work on .net 4.6.1

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-2.0, .net-standard-2.0, .net-4.7

Start new project, pick .netcore2 console app.
Change the target framework to .net 461. You do this by editing the .csproj file as shown:

```xml
<TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
```

netcore has ran on the full framework for years. so no surprises. now add a new project: .net standard 2.0 class library. your .csproj on that library should now contain

```xml
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
```

reference this standard 2 assembly from your console app. Your .csproj file for the console app now reads:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\LibStandard\LibStandard.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

create an enum on your .net standard 2 library

```csharp
namespace LibStandard
{
    public class Class1
    {

    }

    public enum TestEnum
    {
        One, Two
    }

}
```

use said enum in your console app

```csharp
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestEnum t = TestEnum.One;
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

works. cool. Now change your target framework on the console app to .net471. like so

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net471</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\LibStandard\LibStandard.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

and now you will get this error on build:

```
2>Program.cs(10,13,10,21): error CS0012: The type 'Enum' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
2>Program.cs(10,26,10,34): error CS0012: The type 'Enum' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
2>Program.cs(10,35,10,38): error CS0012: The type 'Enum' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
2>Done building project "ConsoleOne.csproj" -- FAILED.
```

I tried adding (via nuget) .netstandard 2.0.0 to the console app project, but that doesn't solve the problem.

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net471</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NETStandard.Library" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\LibStandard\LibStandard.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

If you haven't tried this before, you could always run .net standard libraries in 461 for 1.x standard. But the same doesn't work for .netstandard 2 and 471. You can also try adding a new console app (desktop app full netcore 471). Same result. Starting with a .netcore console app and then targeting the .netfx or starting without .net core gets the same error.

I'm stumped.

SAMPLE SOLUTION: [SAMPLE](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/files/1461883/LibStandard.zip)

Comment: Join the GitHub discussions, like https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/514

Comment: added to https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25177

Answer (score 2):

Seems related to this per VS team
https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/pull/2567

workaround seems to work: add `_HasReferenceToSystemRuntime`

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net471</TargetFramework>
    <_HasReferenceToSystemRuntime>true</_HasReferenceToSystemRuntime>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

seems Visual Studio still a bit confused dealing with .net standard